# How to use attachInterrupt() inside a Class in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt, esp32

I'm working on ESP32+ADS1256 project in Arduino IDE. For maximum performance the SPI data transfer should be accompanied with interrupts on DRDY signal from ADS1256. I'm stuck on adding interrupt into the library:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, DRDY_Interuppt, FALLING);
```

The .ino code:

```
#include "ADS1256LIB.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#define ADS1256_DRATE_30000SPS 0xF0
#define ADS1256_GAIN_1 0x00

#define ADS_RST_PIN 4  //ADS1256 reset pin
#define ADS_RDY_PIN 2  //ADS1256 data ready
#define ADS_CS_PIN 5   //ADS1256 chip select
#define SPI_SPEED 2500000
float vref = 2.5;
volatile int DRDY_state = HIGH;

ADS1256 ADC(ADS_RST_PIN, ADS_CS_PIN, SPI_SPEED, vref, true);

void setup() {

ADC.begin(ADS1256_DRATE_15SPS,ADS1256_GAIN_1,false,ADS_RDY_PIN); 

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

cpp:

```
#include "ADS1256LIB.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SPI.h"

volatile int DRDY_state = HIGH;

ADS1256::ADS1256(int RESET_pin, int CS_pin, long SPI_SPEED, float vref, bool useResetPin) {
  // Set DRDY as input
  
  _SPI_SPEED=SPI_SPEED;
  _RESET_pin=RESET_pin;
  _CS_pin=CS_pin;

  // Set CS as output
  pinMode(_CS_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(_CS_pin, LOW);

  if (useResetPin) {
    // set RESETPIN as output
     pinMode(_RESET_pin, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(_RESET_pin, HIGH);
  }

  // Voltage Reference
  _VREF = vref;

  // Start SPI on a quarter of ADC clock speed
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(_SPI_SPEED, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
}

void ADS1256::begin(unsigned char drate, unsigned char gain, bool buffenable, int ADS_RDY_PIN) {
  
  pinMode(ADS_RDY_PIN, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, DRDY_Interuppt, FALLING);

  _pga = 1 << gain;
  sendCommand(SDATAC);  // send out SDATAC command to stop continous reading mode.
  writeRegister(DRATE, drate);  // write data rate register
  uint8_t bytemask = B00000111;
  uint8_t adcon = readRegister(ADCON);
  uint8_t byte2send = (adcon & ~bytemask) | gain;
  writeRegister(ADCON, byte2send);
  if (buffenable) {
    uint8_t status = readRegister(STATUS_);
    bitSet(status, 1);
    writeRegister(STATUS_, status);
  }
  sendCommand(SELFCAL);  // perform self calibration
  waitDRDY();
  ;  // wait ADS1256 to settle after self calibration
}
void ADS1256::writeRegister(unsigned char reg, unsigned char wdata) {
  CSON();
  SPI.transfer(WREG | reg);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  SPI.transfer(wdata);
  delayMicroseconds(7);
  CSOFF();
}

unsigned char ADS1256::readRegister(unsigned char reg) {
  unsigned char readValue;
  CSON();
  SPI.transfer(RREG | reg);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  delayMicroseconds(7);
  readValue = SPI.transfer(0);
  delayMicroseconds(8);  
  CSOFF();

  return readValue;
}

void ADS1256::sendCommand(unsigned char reg) {
  CSON();
  waitDRDY();
  SPI.transfer(reg);
  delayMicroseconds(8);  
  CSOFF();
}
void ADS1256::waitDRDY() {
  while (DRDY_state) {
    continue;
  }
  noInterrupts();
  DRDY_state = HIGH;
  interrupts();
}

//Interrupt function
void ADS1256::DRDY_Interuppt() {
  DRDY_state = LOW;
}

}
```

h:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SPI.h"

// ADS1256 Register
#define STATUS_ 0x00
#define MUX 0x01
#define ADCON 0x02
#define DRATE 0x03
#define IO 0x04
#define OFC0 0x05
#define OFC1 0x06
#define OFC2 0x07
#define FSC0 0x08
#define FSC1 0x09
#define FSC2 0x0A

// ADS1256 Command
#define WAKEUP 0x00
#define RDATA 0x01
#define RDATAC 0x03
#define SDATAC 0x0f
#define RREG 0x10
#define WREG 0x50
#define SELFCAL 0xF0
#define SELFOCAL 0xF1
#define SELFGCAL 0xF2
#define SYSOCAL 0xF3
#define SYSGCAL 0xF4
#define SYNC 0xFC
#define STANDBY 0xFD
#define RESET 0xFE

class ADS1256 {
public:
  ADS1256(int RESET_pin, int CS_pin, long SPI_SPEED, float vref, bool useResetPin);
  void begin(unsigned char drate, unsigned char gain, bool bufferenable, int ADS_RDY_PIN);
  void DRDY_Interuppt();
  void sendCommand(unsigned char cmd);
  void waitDRDY();
  void writeRegister(unsigned char reg, unsigned char wdata);
  unsigned char readRegister(unsigned char reg);

private:
  byte _pga;
  float _VREF;
  float _conversionFactor;
  int _DRDY_pin;   //Pin assigned for DRDY
  int _RESET_pin;  //Pin assigned for RESET
  int _CS_pin;     //Pin assigned for CS
  long _SPI_SPEED; // SPI SPEED, Hz
};
```

How can I add attachInterrupt support to this library?

I tried moving attachInterrupt() to ino file but then the methods inside the library won't work since they refer to the waitDRDY() function.

Comment: Is this a class where you anticipate there ever being multiple instances?  If so then how will you determine which instance gets the interrupt?  If not, then could this class be a singleton?  Then you can have the ISR in the .cpp file and let it just call the appropriate method on your singleton instance.  This would be similar to how the Serial class works.

Comment: Its a single instance class but if I could set an unique interrupt pin to each instance it would be great.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense at all.  You say it's intended to be a single instance, then say something about "each instance" which implies that there may be more than one.  It can't be both.  The answer is different in each case.  If there will only ever be one of these things connected to a given project (like Serial) then you can use a singleton.  If you want to be able to have more than one of them and each one has a different interrupt then each interrupt needs to be able to know the instance that it belongs to and that can't be done from inside the instance unless it is static.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you how it is. [attachInterrupt()](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/855f5261913c74e9f4f99fc0de184c847cc4db59/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-gpio.h#L78) in esp32-hal-gpio.h expects a plain C-style function pointer. Class methods cannot be represented as plain function pointers and they're not compatible with any API that expects those. That's because a regular class member maintains two pieces of information - the member itself and the object it's attached to. This does not fit into a function pointer. The standard (cumbersome) solution is to make your class a singleton holding a static method which can be passed to that interrupt API. A very naive solution looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() { _instance = this; }
  static void mainIsr() { Foo::getInstance()->onInterrupt(); }
  static Foo* getInstance() { return _instance; }
private:
  void onInterrupt() { /* Handle interrupt */ }
  Foo* _instance = nullptr;
};

...
attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, Foo::mainIsr, FALLING);
```

This code has a bunch of singleton's good practices omitted for brevity.

Meanwhile Espressif's Arduino Core seems to offer an interesting alternative - [`FunctionalInterrupt`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/855f5261913c74e9f4f99fc0de184c847cc4db59/cores/esp32/FunctionalInterrupt.h#L18) which accepts an `std::function` instead of plain function pointer. This is an advanced function pointer which allows you to bind a class member. Adapting the [example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/855f5261913c74e9f4f99fc0de184c847cc4db59/libraries/ESP32/examples/GPIO/FunctionalInterrupt/FunctionalInterrupt.ino#L29) to your circumstances:

```
#include <FunctionalInterrupt.h>
...
void ADS1256::begin(unsigned char drate, unsigned char gain, bool buffenable, int ADS_RDY_PIN) {
  pinMode(ADS_RDY_PIN, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, std::bind(&ADS1256::DRDY_Interuppt, this), FALLING);
...
```

Disclaimer: I have not tried this personally, just looked at the header. The downside of this alternative is that it plops over 200KB of STL code into your binary. I usually consider it an acceptable tradeoff, as I use STL for other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

I seem a bit late to the party, but there is a library BindArg for Arduino for using object instance methods as interrupt handlers (https://github.com/openlab-vn-ua/BindArg).

```
#include <BindArg.h>
```

In your implementation of `ADS1256::begin`
replace:

```
attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, DRDY_Interuppt, FALLING);
```

with:

```
attachInterrupt(ADS_RDY_PIN, bindArgGateThisAllocate(&ADS1256::DRDY_Interuppt, this), FALLING);
```

This allows you to implement `DRDY_Interuppt` as a non-static instance member.

*This is the simplest solution since you have no `end` method (and so you do not need to call `bindArgGateFree`).*